# how to display Django model based form to the center of page(Crispy form)

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to use the crispy form for Django model-based form. I have referred a few questions already asked but no luck I did not found the way how to centralize the Crispy form.

Please find the below code.

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(label=' Enter Username',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'LDAPID/AppleConnect'}))
password = forms.CharField(label='Enter Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'alphanumeric password'}))
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
email = forms.CharField(label='Enter Email ID', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'abc@apple.com'}))
# username = forms.CharField(label=_("Enter LDAP ID"), widget=MyPasswordInput

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
    # It builds a default layout with all its fields
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.form_class = 'vertical-form'

    # You can dynamically adjust your layout
    self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'save'))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    help_texts = {
        'username': None,}
```

**HTML file:**

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container" align=''>

        <div class="alert warning">
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
            Please Read the below Instruction Carefully.<br>
            <strong>Alert!</strong> <br>
            1. In
            <span2> Username</span2>
            enter your ldap ID and in
            <span2>Email</span2>
            field enter apple Email.<br>&nbsp&nbsp
            2.Once the Account created user will not have Access to the respective Portal.To get Access please file
            radar with business justification(User should be part of vendor Company group).

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            <div class="form-row" col-md-8>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0  align=center">
            
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            {{form|crispy}}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" value="Click to SignUp"
                                   onclick="return confirm('Thank you redirecting you to login Page.');">
                        </form>
              
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


    </div>

    {%endblock%}
```

Image :
[image]

any help/Suggestion on this would be appreciated.

Comment: 'align=center' in your div.form-group does not work. instead use: center or align-center

Comment: @barbaart Thanks!, I have Checked but no change in form, and if I am using  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> then it is stretching but I want the same form to align to center.

Comment: i will fix this for you in a few hours, kinda busy right now!

Comment: Okay, thanks! @barbaart.

Comment: @Hi barbaart, Issue has been resolved after using     <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 ">